# Pasar un objeto a un controlador desde una vista en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de encontrar el modo de pasar un objeto desde una vista a un controlador en Laravel 5.2.

La vista contiene un Form y el objeto `$user` es accesible en la vista.

Quisiera conocer alguna forma de acceder al objeto `$user` en el controlador que es llamado cuando se hace el submit del Form.

La vista desde donde `$user` es accesible:

**credential.blade.php:**

```
<div id="container" align="center">
     {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'UsersController@setCredentials', 'method' => 'POST' )) }}

     {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/credential', 'UsersController@setCredentials');
```

El controlador donde quisiera poder acceder al objeto $user.

**UsersController.php**

```
public function setCredentials() {

  $this->user= $user;
}
```

Comment: Si entiendo bien, en la vista credential.blade.php recibes un usuario $user y quieres después obtener ese mismo $user en el controlador?

Comment: Si eso es exactamente lo que quiero. Me serviría saber si de alguna forma se pudiera agregar ese objeto a los datos que se envían en el POST o cualquier otra forma de finalmente poder acceder a ese objeto en el controlador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes enviar el id del objeto user en un campo oculto

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$user->id}}">
```

y en tu controller solo deberías hacer esto (suponiendo que tu modelo se llame User)

```
 $user = User::find(Request::input('id'));
```

Comment: Aunque puede que funcione, realmente no sigue las buenas prácticas de Laravel, además de hacer una llamada innecesaria al modelo en el controlador.

Comment: Coincido en tu comentario, solo una cuestión en la respuesta que diste tengo una pequeña duda, al pasar $user->id como parámetro, según entiendo solo estas pasando el id del $user, pero no el usuario completo?, gracias por el comentario :)!

Comment: Pasa "completo" solo con el id y Laravel se encarga del resto, sería imposible (al menos hasta donde yo sé) pasar el objeto completo en la URL.

Comment: Gracias por aclarar mi duda!

Comment: En efecto esta solución me funciona sin problemas, salvo que en el controlador asigne $user así: `$user = User::find(Input::get('id'));`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar el modelo directamente a la URL, gracias al [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding) de Laravel:

El formulario, utilizando [Form Model Binding](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#form-model-binding):

```
Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user.setCredentials', $user->id]])
```

La ruta:

```
Route::post('credential/{user}', 'UsersController@setCredentials')->name('user.setCredentials');
```

En el controlador:

```
public function setCredentials(User $user) {

  $this->user= $user;
}
```

Comment: Al intentar tu solución ocurre una excepción MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: Tal vez el formulario está enviando un GET u otro verbo distinto a POST, o falta el campo del token CSRF, aunque todo esto debería estar incluido por defecto. Puedes mirar el listado de rutas y verbos disponibles con artisan.

Comment: Si ya había pensado en eso y también había verificado el listado de rutas, no sé si model binding se aplica bien a mi caso, me remito a la otra solución que me funciona sin problema, gracias de todos modos.

Comment: De hecho model binding funciona perfecto en cualquier caso.  En la otra solución como lo expliqué en un comentario, no sigue las buenas prácticas de Laravel.

Comment: Comprendo, voy a darle otra vuelta a tu solución y analizar a fondo como funciona, gracias.